# memory usage of a PHP array when adding a huge numeric key

Tags: php, arrays, memory-management

If I want to use a PHP non-associative array like a dictionary and add a big key, how much memory will PHP allocate?

```
$myArray = Array();
$myArray[6000] = "string linked to ID 6000";
$myArray[7891] = "another key-value pair";
```

Will PHP also allocate memory for the unused keys 0-5999 and 6001-7890?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, PHP doesn't implement this like a C style array. Php arrays are associative containers, as the [php article on arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) states.

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered
>   map. A map is a type that associates
>   values to keys.

Since order is preserved, the array will likely be some kind of binary search tree. If you're unfamiliar with binary search trees I suggest picking up a good data structures book to learn more or check out [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) for a rundown. Your example above would yield a binary search tree with two nodes -- one for data at key 6000, the other for key 7891.

Comment: Note that if you pass this through json_encode(), that'll create the 0-5999 keys - json doesn't like PHP's sparse arrays.

Comment: When I do `$myArray[strtotime($date)] = ...` this runs of of memory, which seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: No, whupps. I was trying to index a string with a huge number. That WILL crash. Stupid dynamic typing.

Answer (score 2):

It won't allocate memory for indexes 0-5999.